# Does cartilage connect to other cartilage?

Tags: human-anatomy

In the definition of a [Ligament in Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ligament) states:

> A short band of tough, flexible fibrous connective tissue which
>   connects two bones or cartilages or holds together a joint.

the wording of "two" prior to bones or cartilages sounds like it could be bone to bone, cartilage to cartilage, and bone to cartilage.

Are all of these combinations correct? If so, is there a good example where each one can be seen for reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ligament can connect **two bones**:

[image]

*Picture 1: Knee joint ligaments (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knee), Creative Commons license)*

A ligament can connect **two cartilages** or a **bone and a cartilage:**

[image]

*Picture 2: Larynx ligaments (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larynx), Creative Commons license)*

Ligaments can also connect **internal organs:**

[image]

*Picture 3: Ligaments connecting abdominal organs (source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LesserSacCS2a.jpg), Creative Commons license)*